# Updating only columns that are not null

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a table and i want to use only the columns that are not null

for example:

```
PhysicalNo  Set Gush    Helka id        Meshalem    Street
10B715      222 20963   16    311572895     
10B718          20963   16    324555986     
10B724      222 20963   16          
10B727      222 20963   16    55672315      
10B72A      222 20963   16    55672315      
10B72D      222         17    51381507      
10B730      222 20963               
10B733      222 20963   17    13855184      
10B736      222         17          
10B739          20963   17    13855184      
10B73C      222 20963   17    50272236      
10B73F      222 20963   17          
10B742      222 20963   17    50272236      
10B745          20963   17          
10B748
```

the query will update only columns "PhysicalNo  Set Gush    Helka".
without changing the query every time it will check if the column is not null first and then update.

Comment: Any reason this is tagged "VBA"? Also, please [edit] your question with the query you currently have.

Comment: Also please tell us what Database do you use ? Oacle, MySQL or something else ?

Comment: its in access but i can also use vba in the moudle

Comment: i can use sql query

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, you can phrase this as:

```
update t 
    set PhysicalNo  = nz(PhysicalNo, 0),
        [Set] nz([Set], 0),
        Gush = nz(Gush, 0),
        Helka = nz(Helka, 0)
    where PhysicalNo is null or [Set] is null or
          Gush is null or Helka is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

can i loop throu all columns and get list if columns is not nulls

PhysicalNo  Set Gush    Helka id        Meshalem    Street
10B715      222 20963   16    311572895
10B718          20963   16    324555986
10B724      222 20963   16
10B727      222 20963   16    55672315
10B72A      222 20963   16    55672315
10B72D      222         17    51381507
10B730      222 20963
10B733      222 20963   17    13855184
10B736      222         17
10B739          20963   17    13855184
10B73C      222 20963   17    50272236
10B73F      222 20963   17
10B742      222 20963   17    50272236
10B745          20963   17
10B748

the loop will give me Meshalem Street, in like this example in vba that loop throu tables. i wwant it to loop throu columes of table

`Set dB = Application.CurrentData

For Each tbl In db.AllTables

Debug.Print tbl.Name`